# is BLE SPP full duplex?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a project that requires BLE Serial Profile.

I have successfully implemented it, but now I'm wondering what happens when server is sending data to the client, and client wants to send data back (while server is still sending). Is this handled on the low level with a queue or something similar?

Is there any risk that messages will get lost?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since there is no "official" BLE Serial Profile, I'm pretty sure you are using a manufacturer's own implementation with that manufacturer's hardware. Since we do not have a working crystal ball, it would probably be easiest to direct this question to the manufacturer of this hardware.

Comment: Since most small bluetooth devices will use the same antenna to transmit and receive, it cannot be instantaneously full duplex, it must queue data that it wants to transmit while it is receiving and vice versa for the other device.  How long that queue is and whether it is visible to the application protocol depends on the implementation as suggested by Risto.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth provides the effect of full duplex transmission through the use of time division duplex (TDD). In principle transmission and reception do not happen at the same time. So in your case there is no risk of collision (loss) of data packets.
[image: Timeslot]

As you can see "Central" and "Peripheral" have a window of 625us during which they transmit.

For further details you can read "Timeslot" chapter of the base band specification in Core Bluetooth specification.
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/

Comment: You are describing Bluetooth Classic, while the question was for Bluetooth Low Energy. In any case, BLE as well is only "half duplex" since the radio cannot both send and receive data at the same time. This should however be seen as transparent at a lower layer.

Comment: Central and Peripheral are terms from BLE.